# How can I make a hexa grid follow a curvy shape without it being deformed?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I'm getting stuck at making the grid of the radio below.:

[image]

I can make a hexa grid using Array modifiers, but I don't know how to deform it like in the picture.

Here's what my base mesh looks like:

[image]

I find it hard to make the grid follow the curvy shape circled in Red. My best attempt is this:

[image]

You can see that that part is heavily deformed. This attemp I use two curve modifiers to follow two curves, one horizontal and one vertical. I think that with this sorts of situations, the best way is to use Shrinkwrap to wrap the grid around the curvy shape, but that method results in heavy deformation. Circles don't look like circles any more. What is the best solution for this?

Here's my Blend file if necessary: [retroRadio.blend](https://filebin.net/26u7p50iesd9mv59)

Comment: if we take a look at some close-up pictures of this radio, the grid actually doesn't look like what you've done: https://zupimages.net/up/19/40/hjj9.jpg  so maybe you should try to build a mesh that looks like that, then I guess it would save a lot of memory to bake this mesh and only keep a simple rounded beveled surface

Comment: Thank you, moon. I'll try re-make the base mesh, but still, how can I deform the grid like in the picture in your comment?

Comment: Looking at your picture, I think it may work to use Mesh Deform modifier. The idea is to use a mesh to deform the grid, then attach it to the radio. What do you think?

Comment: I'm looking how to do it, maybe with Cast modifier? Old tuto by CGMaster about a microphone, it may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NhawJgrBKw   if it's not very important to stick to the real thing you can also fake it. Another problem is to find how to make round holes...

Comment: @moonboots: You may check these answers for making the hexa grid. https://bit.ly/2pf0gBv. Btw, I still cant see how to use Cast modifier to achieve that shape yet. The broader question would be, how can we make a hexa grid follow an arbitrary curvy surface without the circles being deformed? The way I see it, the cast modifier is limited to three shapes, so I think it's not a long-term solution. I think the answers are very likely to lie in the Shrinkwrap modifier and a combination of a deform modifier such as Mesh Deform/Lattice/Surface deform and Proportional Edit.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get something rather good with this method:

- First here is a close-up shot of your radio.

[image]

- Create a mesh > *Geodesic Dome* with these parameters (or similar):

[image]

- Select all, bevel the vertices with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. Then delete O*nly Faces*.

[image]

- Keep only 1/8th of the ball, you have your corner. Enable the *Snap* (*Vertex* mode) and the *Merge Vertices* options. Begin to duplicate the borders to make the flat surface.

[image]

- At the end give it a *Subdivision Surface* and a *Solidify* modifier. Maybe a *Shrinkwrap* if you want to correct the shape a bit.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this black magic. I'll try it for this model, but still, I will try to find a long-term solution for these sorts of situations. Will comment here if I figure it out.